# Main content in HTML5

Tags: html

Let's say, I **always** want to use the `main` element in a project for different page types. One of these page types is just a product page, with a header and some sections. Which variant would be semantically correct:

A

```
<body>
    <header>
        ...
    </header>
    <main>
        <header>
            <h1>...</h1>
            <img />
        </header>
        <section>
            <h1>...</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>...</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

B

```
<body>
    <header>
        ...
    </header>
    <main>
        <article>
            <header>
                <h1>...</h1>
                <img />
            </header>
            <section>
                <h1>...</h1>
                <p>...</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h1>...</h1>
                <p>...</p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer>
        ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

I would say `A` can't be correct. Accordingly to the working draft:

> The `header` element represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element.
>
> The `main` element is not sectioning content and has no effect on the document outline.

Thus the `body > main > header` in `A` would represents the *introductory content* for `body` which is the *sectioning root element*.

For those who might ask, why you don't use `B` without `main`. This has technical reasons either I always use `main` or not. And there are other page types with multiple articles in the main content.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Which variant would be semantically correct? And can be variant `A` semantically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example *A* is not correct. I can think of no content where example *A* would make sense.

You gave the correct explanation why this is the case:

The [`header`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-header-element) belongs to its "nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element".

In example *A*, both `header` elements would belong to `body` (= nearest sectioning root element), but only the first `header` should belong to it, while the second `header` should belong to the product.

As `main` is not a sectioning content element, you’d need to use one here. `article` seems to be the correct choice (as all its content is about a product), so example *B* looks fine.